# Is it possible to reset a Normal Mode playthrough?

Tags: borderlands-2

So, I accidentally left my game running in friends only overnight. Then, a rather irritating friend of mine came in with his level 35 Commando and finished from A Dam Fine Rescue to Rising Action,leaving me underleveled, gear-wise. Is this fixable or am I up some sort of creek without a bladed Jakobs sniper rifle?

Comment: not without using an editor, and if you are going to do that, may as well just set your level and your gear level to something higher...

Comment: "up some sort of creek without a bladed Jakobs sniper rifle" lol. You could always restart the game entirely. A Dam Fine Rescue isn't that far into the game IIRC.

Comment: If you are playing on PC, BL2 keeps a backup of your current save that tends to be a bit older.  It may be before your friend joined.  I'm not sure how often the current save gets written to the backup though.

Comment: You may be able to join another friend's game who hasn't progressed as far as you.  You won't get the XP from the missions you've already "completed", but that might be a good thing, since your friend will catch up a bit in level while playing with you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest grinding nonstop to get on his league. No, you cannot restart without an editor, as far as I know.